# WPF : Extend Theme's style - StackOverflowException

Tags: wpf, themes, styles

I want every button to have 5 points margin, in addition to Royale theme style.

Window1.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="_styles.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Royale;component/themes/royale.normalcolor.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Button A"/>
    <Button Content="Button B"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

It compiles but I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

```
public Window1() {
    InitializeComponent(); // <-- getting exception here
}
```

There are no exception details because:

> {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}

Comment: Can you give us any indication of where the exception is raised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a circular reference between your style and the one defined in PresentationFramework.Royale. A workaroud would be to place resources at different levels:

```
<Window x:Class="_styles.Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Royale;component/themes/royale.normalcolor.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Content="Button A"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can anyone explain how was this causing circular reference and why changing the scope has resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the BasedOn attribute - it's not necessary. Think of it this way, merging the Royale theme will apply the button theme, and you just want to change the margin - styles are additive in nature, so it will combine the Royale theme *and* your own button theme without specifying the BasedOn attribute - does that make sense?

Cheers!

Comment: I was under impression that closer-scoped style *overwrites* previous style, i.e. at most one style can be applied. And BasedOn attribute is the way to *extend* a style.

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right.  That's interesting - I tried the suggestion I gave you using the Aero theme, and leaving out the BasedOn="..." resets the buttons style back to the original XP theme.  Woops :)  

If you can share more of the source, perhaps I could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901664/how-do-i-alter-the-default-style-of-a-button-without-wpf-reverting-from-aero-to-c) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901664/how-do-i-alter-the-default-style-of-a-button-without-wpf-reverting-from-aero-to-c/3093183#3093183) for another solution that doesn't require you to specify a resource dictionary in every window and allows you to resolve the BasedOn style dynamically.