# How do I alter the default style of a button without WPF reverting from Aero to Classic?

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

I've added PresentationFramework.Aero to my App.xaml merged dictionaries, as in...

```
<Application
    x:Class="TestApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary
                     Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFToolkit;component/Themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="/CommonLibraryWpf;component/ResourceDictionaries/ButtonResourceDictionary.xaml" />
                    <!-- Note, ButtonResourceDictionary.xaml is defined in an external class library-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I'm trying to modify the default look of buttons just slightly. I put this style in my ButtonResourceDictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

All buttons now have the correct padding and bold text, but they look "Classic", not "Aero". How do I fix this style so my buttons all look Aero but also have these minor changes? I would prefer not to have to set the `Style` property for every button.

**Update**

I should have mentioned this in the first place, but if I try to use `BasedOn`, as shown below, I get a `StackOverflowException`:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

This would normally work, but not with the Aero dictionaries merged in. If I comment those dictionaries out, the exception disappears.

**Update 2**

If I add an `x:Key` attribute and manually set the style, it works properly (Aero style with padding and bold), but as I said, I'd prefer that the style is automatically applied globally to all buttons.

**Update 3**

I just discovered a new wrinkle. In my app, ButtonResourceDictionary.xaml is placed in a class library (i.e., in an external project). If I move this file to a local folder, everything works fine. So, the problem seems to be a bad interaction caused by referencing various external resource dictionaries. I'm correcting my App.xaml code snippet (above) to reflect that ButtonResourceDictionary is actually defined externally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope you've found a solution in the meantime. For everyone else, [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927251/wpf-extend-themes-style-stackoverflowexception/1542805#1542805) workaround, and [here is another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780817/wpf-override-standard-theme-in-app-xaml/2223751#2223751). I am not sure whether this will help for your specific case though (especially the fact that you reference an embedded resource dictionary).

**UPDATE**

Here's a solution I came up with:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{Common:StaticApplicationResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="21"/>
</Style>
```

Where `StaticApplicationResource` is a custom MarkupExtension I wrote that simply calls `TryFindResource`:

```cs
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class StaticApplicationResource : MarkupExtension
{
    public StaticApplicationResource(object pResourceKey)
    {
        mResourceKey = pResourceKey;
    }

    private object _ResourceKey;

    [ConstructorArgument("pResourceKey")]
    public object mResourceKey
    {
        get { return _ResourceKey; }
        set { _ResourceKey = value; }
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (mResourceKey == null)
            return null;

        object o = Application.Current.TryFindResource(mResourceKey);

        return o;
    }
}
```

This way I don't have to reference my resource dictionaries outside of my App.xaml file , which is the way I like it :). You can also put more complicated logic in there too, allowing you to resolve the BasedOn style any way you like. [Here is an excellent article](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/02/14/wpfdefaulttemplate) showing you how to load resource dictionaries (and those that the framework resolves automatically) from code.

Comment: Thanks, Andre. Good answer. I basically solved the problem using a technique similar to your first workaround. I moved my customizations to the default button style from the App level to the Window level.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BasedOn attribute to inherit the properties from the Aero Style. This should solve your problem.

```
<Style
  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
  TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> 
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" /> 
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" /> 
</Style>
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but for some reason, it causes a `StackOverflowException`. And, interestingly, if I comment out the the Aero merged dictionaries, the exception doesn't happen. So, for some reason, when you merge in Aero, you can't base a style on it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updates, you could do this (admittedly it is hideously ugly):

```
<Style x:Key="_buttonStyleBase"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> 
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" /> 
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" /> 
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource _buttonStyleBase}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Abe, but it still causes a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: Missing one close brace `}`, should be:`<Style
  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
  TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> `

Comment: Thanks for fixing it!